# обновить определённое количество записей в бд laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как правильно найти в базе указанное количество строк(по имени) и записать в них моё значение?
К примеру у меня есть $user_id= '777'  $count = '4' и $lang= 'en'.Наверное логика моих действий должна быть такова

- Мне нужно использовать DB::select('lang')->find($lang) для того что бы обратиться к таблице и найти в ней соответствующее поле lang.
- потом скорее всего мне нужно брать $count и циклом делать update на это количество раз с каждым циклом добавляя $user_id в мою таблицу

Я новичок в laravel и php ,помогите пожалуйста не делать велосипед и сделать правильное решение. Пример кода или что то похожее было бы идеально!

Comment: Почитайте про  [работу с бд](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent) в их документации, там всё подробно описано с примерами кода.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин  читал, у меня получается найти и перезаписать то, что мне нужно путем: $curr_table = my_db::where('user_lang','=', $lang)->update(['user_id'=> $user_id]))Это работает, не берет во внимание $count. Возможно мне нужно поискать еще внимательнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала вы должны найти строки, которые хотите обновить.
Что бы ограничить вашу выборку после where используйте limit()

```
$curr_table = my_db::where('user_lang','=', $lang)
                     ->limit($count)
                     ->update(['user_id'=> $user_id]))
```

Comment: да, Вы абсолютно правы! Я разобрался с этим еще вчера, но физически не было возможности дать ответ на свой же вопрос здесь)Я добавил еще whereNull() и это позволило более точно делать запись в моем случае! Спасибо за ответ!!!
Мой вариант:
db::where('user_lang','=', $lang)->whereNull('user_id')->take($count)->update(['user_id'=> $user_id]);